# Joomla using default Apache on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: apache, macos, joomla

Is anyone familiar with Joomla? And how do I install it using default Apache2 installation on Mac OS X Snow Leopard instead of installing another version of Apache installing Joomla using that server instead?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I don't think there is much difference to installing it on any other Apache system. Just follow the docs, it should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once Apache2 is properly set up in Snow Leopard, it is the same process to get a joomla site up and running as any other lamp server. ( unzip files ,create database ,walk through configuration)
Have you gotten apache2 set up with php and mysql? I recently had to go through that and not everything was too straight forward. I found this to be a good bit of help http://maestric.com/doc/mac/apache_php_mysql_snow_leopard

Comment: yes but there is no "htdocs" folder I can find under /etc/apache2. And "htdocs" is the folder where the The "Joomla Quick Start Guide" asks me to unzip Joomla.
I'm new to both Mac OS X and Joomla. Thanks for help.

Comment: the web root folder is defined in your Apache configuration file (usually "/etc/httpd.conf") in a definition called 'DocumentRoot'. See here: http://somethingcliche.com/2010/02/10/change-apaches-webroot-in-osx-10-6/